# Azure for parallel Math computations in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, math, azure, parallel-processing

I have a multi threaded C# application which performs mathematical computations. The results of all threads are brought together to produce the required result.

I would love to be able to use cloud computing to take this a lot further than my 8 core PC can go.

I have looked at a lot of documentation for Microsoft Azure and am still unclear about where to start or if what I'm wanting to do is even possible. I'd love to be able to fire off 1,000 threads in a cloud computing environment and have the results from each merged into my final results.

A sample application that does multi threaded / parallel math computing on Azure would be really helpful... a basic no bells and whistles Math computing example, like calculating Pi using parallel processing on Azure or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a cluster of computers to tackle a calculation problem is not as simple as fire off threads on a single machine. To tackle this type of problems, you should review [Map Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapreduce) strategies/technologies such as [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).  Check the [Hadoop on Azure Pi Estimator Sample Tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13807.the-hadoop-on-azure-pi-estimator-sample-tutorial.aspx) (Java) to get a feeling for what is required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I might be wrong but is that a Java based solution? I get what you mean about it not being simply a matter of firing off threads. I guess I was hoping for a way to take the bulk of my existing c# code which is already setup for parallel processing and then have that code execute on multiple 'threads'/cores/PC's and then the final step of communicating the results so they can be collated. I can merge the results myself even if I just got 1,000 file outputs back.

Comment: I created an Azure account and setup a virtual machine and thought about doing it that way... but then I'd have to setup 100's or 1000's of virtual machines which seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: There is no database or input data... I simply have a function which then performs calculations and returns a two dimensional array. I have designed that function so it can be executed over various ranges... hence I can run multiple threads over various ranges.

Comment: The challenges with distributed computing are related to the reliability of the nodes (computers) in the cluster, and the need for them to reliability communicate with one another.  In your case, how would you handle if the `collating node` crashes?  Should the working nodes keep waiting until it comes back online? And given the cloud resources you plan to use, there is a cost associated with a given solution.

Comment: Hadoop is writen in Java, but C# can communicate with it via [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html).

Comment: FYI - Azure provides [HDInsight](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/hdinsight/), which is Hadoop-as-a-Service.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments... very helpful. I will mark this answer as correct. Looks like I need to do a lot more research, in the meantime I'm probably going to simply use Azure to create multiple virtual machines and fire off multiple instances of my computation and merge the results back myself.